# How can i get only the first level of childrens in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

If I have this three structure in a table,

```
-A
 |
 *---B
 |   |
 |   *---C
 |   |
 |   *---D
 |       |
 |       *---E
 |       |
 |       *---F
 |       |
 |       *---G
 *---H
     *---I
     |
     *---J
```

assuming list() method is called and it returns a colleccion of B and H. 
In this scenario I would like hibernate obtain C,D,I and J in a single query.(lazy=false is not working because I dont need E,F and G, just the FIRST LEVEL)
thanks a lot

Comment: Please post your table structure and hibernate mapping if have any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to achieve this. Let others know if you find something